# Strange Flask Blueprint behaviour

Tags: python, flask

I have this code (working):

```
bp = Blueprint(...)

@bp.before_request
def before_request():
     if self.auth_callback is not None:
         return self.auth_callback()

 self.app.register_blueprint(
     bp,
     url_prefix=self.config.get("FILE_UPLOAD_PREFIX")
 )
```

---

And this is not working:

```
bp = Blueprint(...)

self.app.register_blueprint(
    bp,
    url_prefix=self.config.get("FILE_UPLOAD_PREFIX")
)

 @bp.before_request
 def before_request():
     if self.auth_callback is not None:
         return self.auth_callback()
```

Can someone explain me, whats happening here plz? Why is the order important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the Flask app won't use the given Blueprint object directly, but save its state in the app at registration with the help of the `BlueprintSetupState` class. If you modify the Blueprint object after it is registered, it will have no effect on the previously saved state.

See the `BlueprintSetupState` class in the [Flask sources](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/blueprints.py) for more details, where its class documentation states the following:

> Temporary holder object for registering a blueprint with the
>   application.  An instance of this class is created by the
>   :meth:`~flask.Blueprint.make_setup_state` method and later passed
>   to all register callback functions.

**EDIT**:
My previous answer was a little misleading, because the callbacks are not saved in the `BlueprintSetupState` instance, but in the App instance. For example, when you give a function to run before each request with `before_request`, the given function will be added to the `before_request_funcs` list of the app instance **at registration**. This is why it has no effect to change the callback after registration. See the `register` and `before_request` methods of the `Blueprint` class.

Comment: That means i can't add wrappers to the Blueprint except using and registering a callback? Or is there any other way?
Nice catch btw, thank your for this information,

Comment: You are welcome. I realized that my answer was lacking some information, so I added a note at the end to fix it. What do you mean by wrappers? Do you mean decorators?

Comment: Yea i mean decorators. But your edit already answerd this question too. Thank you very much